# Convert outlook email to plain text

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, plaintext

I have about 5 email boxes setup in Outlook 2013. I want all incoming emails sent in html to be converted to plaint text, only for one particular mailbox. How can this be achieved? I already know that there is a global option to turn this on, but I only want it for one box in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with VBA.

http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objNS As NameSpace
  Set objNS = Application.Session
  ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
  Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
  Set objNS = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  On Error Resume Next
  Item.BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
  Item.Save
  Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

This line likely has to change.

```
Set olInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
```

You reference the non default inbox like this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076634/outlook-2007-vba-to-get-reference-to-additional-inbox